# Pyspark - a column with time condition

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp, addition, palantir-foundry

I want that once the time is greater than 07:00:00, the date of the column 'tatsaechlicher_einsatztag' should be 'einsatzdatum' + 1, and if the time is less than 07:00:00, then it should be the same day. The problem here is that the code cannot read the string in line 121. Currently, one day is always added because it does not recognize the string.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the '[hours](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.hour.html)' function. You'll need to import this from pyspark.sql e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

To actually perform the comparison it would be something like this.

```
F.hours(F.col("column_name")) < F.lit(7)
```